# Is there a function in c++ using opencv which allows to convert an image to double precision as im2double in MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, type-conversion, double-precision

I'm translating some code developed in MATLAB to C++ using OpenCV. I'm loading an image in the RGB format like:

```
Mat img; 
img = imread('path to directory', CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

I just want to convert this image to double precision as `im2double()` does it in MATLAB. Is there any function which allows to do it? Can I use the `convertTo()` function?

I tried to do:

```
img.convertTo(img, CV_64FC3, 255.0);
```

But it's not working. Could you help me?

UPDATE: Thank you for your answers. What I'm doing now is something like

```
int i, k;
Mat img, img_dbprec;

img = imread('path to directory', CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //Loads the image in the RGB format
img.convertTo(img_dbprec, CV_64FC3,1.0/255.0);//Convert image to double precision
for(i=0; i<img_dbprec.rows; i++){
   for(k=0; k<img_dbprec.cols; k++){
       cout << (double) img_dbprec.data[img_dbprec.step[0]*i + img_dbprec.step[1]* k + 0] << " ";
       cout << (double) img_dbprec.data[img_dbprec.step[0]*i + img_dbprec.step[1]* k + 1] << " ";
       cout << (double) img_dbprec.data[img_dbprec.step[0]*i + img_dbprec.step[1]* k + 2] << endl;
    }
}
```

My output is (I will just put the final values):

```
...

150 150 150
21 21 21
85 85 85
214 213 213
22 22 22
22 22 22
214 213 213
85 85 85
21 21 21
```

which is not what I want. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you be more specific regarding "not working"?

Comment: what happens (in terms of output) if you skip the scale factor (`1.0/255.0`) completely? what is the range of the pixels' values then?

Comment: if I skip the scale factor, I get the same values as in MATLAB (range 0-255) when I read the image. Doing this operation (convertTo), I get this values which are still in the range 0-255 instead of range 0.0-1.0

Comment: so, there is no difference if you are using scale `1.0/255.0` or `1.0`?

Comment: ah no! I didn't understand your question. I tought you said to omit the convertTo function. If I change the scale factor to 1.0 I still get integer values in the range 0-255 but they are different. Now I have a lot of 0's.

Comment: by the way, if I choose the scale factor as 1.0/255.0, I get different values form the ones I get if I choose 1/255.0 or 1.0/255. Shouldn't be the same?

Comment: weird. AFAIK should be the same... how different?

Comment: @Shai, thank you for your help. Actually, the way you said is working. I was not printing the values in the correct way. Using img_dbprec.at<Vec3d>(i,k)[j] (where i are rows, k are columns and j are channels) I get the correct values.

Comment: Great. I'm happy it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your scale factor is inverted. Try:

```
Mat dimg;
img.convertTo( dimg, CV_64FC3, 1.0/255.0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. however, the 255.0 you have inserted, is not the max value of the RGB matrix, but a scaling factor, according to documentation. So, you probably multiply all pixel values by 255, which takes them out of the [0, 255] range. Also, (depends on the version you are using) it would be safer to create a new destination value

```
Mat doubleImg;
img.convertTo(doubleImage, CV_64FC3);
```